# Move record Up and Down Gridview ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got the reference from [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Change-row-Order-Position-in-ASPNet-GridView.aspx)
and here is my aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvExecSummary" CssClass="grid th" runat="server" 
                EmptyDataRowStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" EmptyDataRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" EmptyDataRowStyle-Height="100px"
                EmptyDataRowStyle-BorderWidth="1px" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
                CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" ForeColor="Black" Visible="true    " DataKeyNames="valUrutan" OnRowCommand="gvExecSummary_RowCommand">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#efefef" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="search_textbox4"></asp:Label>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>



                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pekerjaan/Project" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Pekerjaan/Project<br />

                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            &nbsp&nbsp
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lb" runat="server" Text='  <%# Eval("lapPekerjaan") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("lapPekerjaan") %>' CommandName="ShowResume"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User/Client" ControlStyle-Width="350px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            User/Client<br />

                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            &nbsp&nbsp<asp:Label ID="lblUserClient" runat="server" Text='  <%# Eval("lapUser") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Width="350px"></ControlStyle>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Permasalahan/Legal Issue" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Permasalahan/Legal Issue<br />

                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbllegalIssue" runat="server" Text='  <%# Eval("lapPermsl") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status Penyelesaian" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Status Penyelesaian<br />

                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblstatusPenyelesaian" runat="server" Text='  <%# Eval("lapStat") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Person In Charge" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Person In Charge<br />

                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPersonInCharge" runat="server" Text='  <%# Eval("lapPIC") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false" Visible="true">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" ClientIDMode="AutoID" runat="server" CommandName="Ubah" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idLapBulExe") %>'><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Hapus" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idLapBulExe") %>' ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/Images/delete.png" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record ?');"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                     
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader ="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUp" Text="&#x25B2;"  ClientIDMode="AutoID" CssClass="button" OnClick="ChangeUrutan" runat="server"  CommandArgument="up"></asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDown" Text="&#x25BC;"  runat="server" CssClass="button" OnClick="ChangeUrutan"  CommandArgument="down"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>

                <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="100px"></EmptyDataRowStyle>

                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#3a87ad" BackColor="#3a87ad" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

codebehind :

```
protected void ChangeUrutan(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string commandArgument = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        try 
        {

            int rowIndex = ((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex;
            int Urutan = Convert.ToInt32(gvExecSummary.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);
            int lapbulID = Convert.ToInt32(gvExecSummary.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString().Trim()); //this is where i got the error
            Urutan = commandArgument == "up" ? Urutan - 1 : Urutan + 1;
            this.UpdateUrutan(lapbulID, Urutan);

            rowIndex = commandArgument == "up" ? rowIndex - 1 : rowIndex + 1;
            lapbulID = Convert.ToInt32(gvExecSummary.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
            Urutan = Convert.ToInt32(gvExecSummary.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);
            Urutan = commandArgument == "up" ? Urutan + 1 : Urutan - 1;
            this.UpdateUrutan(lapbulID, Urutan);

            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }


    }
    private void UpdateUrutan(int lapbulID, int Urutan)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(common.Constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblT_LapBulExecutive SET valUrutan = @Urutan WHERE IdFungsiExecutive = @Id"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", lapbulID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Urutan", Urutan);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and i got error Input string was not in a correct format at int lapbulID line. Am i missing something ? What can i do to resolve this ?
I tried to TryParse, 1 * Convert.To32int, etc but nothing works. Help

Note: my database also contains the same as this reference, only with more field.

Comment: try the debugger and check the value in Urutan and lapbulID variables in UpdateUrutan method , Add the values here

Comment: tried it, and Urutan value is 4 (which is correct) and lapbulID is 0

Comment: Copy the query from debugging at run time and run the query on command prompt , see is there any error in the query , there's a possibility that the data types are not being matched

Comment: got an error, because no record has an IdFungsiExecutive of 0. I suspect this line of code
 `int lapbulID = Convert.ToInt32(gvExecSummary.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString().Trim())` 
is not right tho. This line is meant to get the selected index's ID value. But im not sure as well

Comment: ok , try the debugger and check the value in rowIndex variable , if it's negative tell me

Comment: tried debugger one more time, and got the rowIndex value = 1 ( im selected the 2nd record ) which is correct right ? But when it hits lapbulID, 'input string was not in a correct format'
Tried the '.ToString()' instead of 'Text.ToString()' also didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of Selected rowIndex using :

```
int rowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
```

Then your code will be :

```
       try 
        {
 if (gvExecSummary.SelectedRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{

           // int rowIndex = ((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex;
             int rowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
            int Urutan = Convert.ToInt32(gvExecSummary.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);
            int lapbulID = Convert.ToInt32(gvExecSummary.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString().Trim()); //this is where i got the error
            Urutan = commandArgument == "up" ? Urutan - 1 : Urutan + 1;
            this.UpdateUrutan(lapbulID, Urutan);

            rowIndex = commandArgument == "up" ? rowIndex - 1 : rowIndex + 1;
            lapbulID = Convert.ToInt32(gvExecSummary.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
            Urutan = Convert.ToInt32(gvExecSummary.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);
            Urutan = commandArgument == "up" ? Urutan + 1 : Urutan - 1;
            this.UpdateUrutan(lapbulID, Urutan);

            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }
```

Comment: `int rowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;` gets an error System.EventArgs does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method ....

Comment: still the same `missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?` under `e.Row.RowIndex;`